# send message as status without a dialog : Android Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on an Android app where we enter some text in edit box and all I want to do is simply send the text which typed (i.e.., edittext.gettext()) to facebook as my status.

The important thing is I don't want a Facebook dialog box to open, just send the message as status without a dialog box.

Is there any way I could post without using dialog box?

Comment: Kittu, if you get a chance, you should accept an answer. It helps you and other who take the time to help on Stack Overflow. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey man. The Graph API is really good. look into me and feed.

download the files form the github, Facebook.java, AsyncFacebookRunner.java, etc...

for example in your ShareOnFacebook.java:

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", message);

        // Uses the Facebook Graph API
        try {
            facebook.request("/me/feed", params, "POST");
            this.finish();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to post the message on one specific friends wal.?

Comment: @Venkat Papana, Change "/me/feed" to "/users-id/feed"

Comment: I have tr this... But getting error. Can you please share your working piece of code?

Comment: Are you using the files from the SDK? It creates a Facebook object and uses that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook's [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) for this; Android has JSON serialization classes available in the `org.json` package. The only part of reasonable complexity is authorization/authentication, for which there's [documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

You may also have luck using the [Facebook's SDK for Android](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

Comment: Hi Nurik,
        firstly  Thanks for your reply. I am using the following code 
               JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                message = json.getString("message");

i guess parseJson(response) is the command which parses the response of server into Json object json here. If I am correct the  server response is coming from the dialog box of facebook for posting

 mFacebook.dialog(Example.this, "stream.publish",new SampleDialogListener());

I am wondering whether there is a way not using dialog.
PLz correct me if I am wrong